# how to create Joomla templates?

Tags: cms, joomla, template

I see a lot of sites selling Joomla templates at a premium but most of them look simple enough to build.

Where can I find some tutorials to create such templates which I can provide users for free?

Comment: On a side note, I find a tag for Drupal but no Joomla. IMHO Joomla deserves separate tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few:

- http://www.absalom.biz/tutorials/Mambo_Template_Tutorial.html
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/creating-your-first-joomla-template/
- http://joomlatp.com/joomla-template-Tutorials/how-to-create-joomla-template-with-dreamweaver.html
- http://www.compassdesigns.net/joomla-tutorials/joomla-template-tutorial
- http://www.compassdesigns.net/joomla-tutorials/joomla-15-template-tutorial (This one is good) you can also find other tutorials relating to design on the same site - http://www.compassdesigns.net/joomla-tutorials/

Good luck and enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

The official Joomla tutorial will walk you through an incredibly simple (albeit stripped-down) template build.

The process is similar to building a template for many popular Content Managers, with it's own quirks here and there.  A Joomla template is largely comprised of an index.php file that is a styled framework of the sites design.  JDOC tags are then used to configure things like module positions that are specific to Joomla (which are then styled through CSS).

http://docs.joomla.org/Tutorial:Creating_a_basic_Joomla!_template

Answer (score 2):

mar10's links are worth reading for advanced stuff, but you can create a template really simply:

1. Create a new folder under `/templates` for your template.
2. Copy the `templateDetails.xml` file from another template and edit it for your template name etc.
3. Create an index.php file and use that as the main template.
4. Wherever you want a module position to go, put this special code: `<jdoc:include type="modules" name="left" />` (where "left" is the module position).
5. Wherever you want the main content to go, put this code: `<jdoc:include type="component" style="content" />`

That's all you need for the absolute basics.

Answer (score 0):

Have to give credit to http://www.artisteer.com/ for creating a Dreamweaver like GUI for Joomla Template building.  It's so scary easy now.  Seems to work for the others (Wordpress, Drupal, etc) as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party on this one, but check out [How-To Joomla's](http://www.howtojoomla.net/how-tos/templates/) section on templates.